# SoapFault exception on localhost only

Tags: php, soap, easyphp

Having searched through the many questions related to this error already posted, I've been unable to find an answer.

When I try and connect to a URL via soap, it works fine on a Godaddy VPS but fails on my localserver (EasyPHP AMP Stack). Open SSL is enabled as is Soap in php's ini settings but does anyone know what I'm missing as I guess it's a config issue?

The code I'm running is

```
$gdAuctionsWSURL = 'http://auctions.godaddy.com/gdAuctionsWS/GdAuctionsBiddingWS.asmx?WSDL';
$gdAuctionsWS = new SoapClient($gdAuctionsWSURL);
```

and the error that only occurs on my local server is

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: 
    [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://auctions.godaddy.com/gdAuctionsWS/GdAuctionsBiddingWS.asmx?WSDL' :
    failed to load external entity "http://auctions.godaddy.com/gdAuctionsWS/GdAuctionsBiddingWS.asmx?WSDL"
```

Comment: I get a permission error when I try to access that WSDL URI, so it's entirely possible they aren't permitting you to get it outside of their network. So I would guess there might either be a separate authentication request you need to perform first/with, or it's not provided outside the network. The error itself is pretty direct, though.

Comment: The exact same script works on a VPS which isn't in the Godaddy network so I'm not sure that's the case.

Comment: Use Fiddler or WireShark to monitor network traffic and see if your local setup is not routing out of the network due to a permissions or other problem.